# Storing large, complex data structures

Tags: xml, database, performance, complexity-theory

I have to store large amounts of complex data.

I'm currently using an XML file, because the complexity of the structures doesn't allow me to
use a (normal) database to store the data.

My question is: **Is there any system (similar to a database) able to process/store large amounts of complex data?** If not, **how can I optimize performance if I store the data in an XML file?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look into [document oriented databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database), like [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you put those XML files into an [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) form (triples) then you can use RDF databases. There is one that is meant to be good for large databases called [4store](http://4store.org/), it is written in C and can be installed in clusters of machines. To query it you can use [SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) query language.

RDF databases are one type of NoSQL databases with the advantage that RDF and SPARQL are w3c standards and therefore it assures portability between different systems.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used OO databases like [ObjectStore](http://web.progress.com/en/objectstore/) on projects that needed to manage extremely complex data structures such as Credit Risk trees and oil pipeline networks. XML is the very, very last technology I would use for such applications. Apart from anything else, representing generalised graphs in XML is a real pain.